# OpenLayers - How to create 2 vector layers; 1 draggable and the other is not?

Tags: openlayers-2

Is there a way to make one vector layer (or a certain kind of feature draggable), while the other types of feature or layer is not?

Answer (score 7):

You mean like this example?

http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/drag-feature.html

See the [DragFeature](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.7/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Control/DragFeature-js.html) control for details. If you do not want to drag all features in a layer then set the geometryTypes property, or add your own custom logic to the onStart event to stop a feature being dragged if itdoes not meet your criteria.

Answer (score 1):

I would comment on @geographika's answer but I don't have any reputation.

In case you need finer control over exactly which feature can be dragged, actually it can't be done from `onStart`. But you can supply `featureCallbacks` as in this example.

```
// these are set up as in drag-feature example
var map = new OpenLayers.Map( /* ... */ );
var vectors = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector( /* ... */ );

// this specialized DragFeature control will only drag the single
// feature which is set as dragger.interesting_feature.
var dragger = new OpenLayers.Control.DragFeature(vectors, {
  autoActivate: false,
  onComplete: function(vertex) {
    // drag complete, do something interesting here
  },
  featureCallbacks: {
    // called when a feature is clicked
    click: function(feature) {
      if (feature === this.interesting_feature) {
        return this.clickFeature(feature); // do the default thing
      }
      // otherwise do nothing
    },
    // called when mouse goes over a feature
    over: function(feature) {
      if (feature === this.interesting_feature) {
        return this.overFeature(feature); // do the default thing
      }
      // otherwise do nothing
    }
  }
});
map.addControl(dragger);

// to use the single-feature drag control, do this
dragger.interesting_feature = my_interesting_feature;
dragger.activate();
```